# JasperReports renders empty pdf

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm just doing a test, i want to print some static text yet it doesn't save pdf.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports     http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="FirstReport">
    <detail>
    <band height="20">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="20" y="0" width="200" height="20" />
            <text>
                <![CDATA[If you don't see this, it didn't work]]>
            </text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The code is:

```
public class PDF {
    public void genereazaRaport() {
        try {
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("jrxml/test.jrxml"));
            JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
        //Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        //parameters.put("Titlu Raport", "PDF JasperReport");
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, new JREmptyDataSource());
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("raport/raport.pdf"));
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, out);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    } catch (JRException e) {
        System.out.println("JRException");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new PDF().genereazaRaport();
}
}
```

And I get a blank page when it save in file. I think it's something that has to do with the datasource but i can't figure what.

Answer (score 0):

Try this jrxml. It will work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="FirstReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30">
<detail>
    <band height="20">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="20" y="0" width="200" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <text><![CDATA[If you don't see this, it didn't work
        ]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Enjoy...